# missing file or assembly tinymcetextbox

Tags: .net, asp.net, html, editor

I have a project I am doing some maintenance work on and have got the solution files etc and attempted to build it and have got the following error:-

Error   4   Could not load file or assembly 'TinyMCETextBox' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

This is a .net 2.0 project. Can anyone give me any pointers on this to get me started? I downloaded the tinymce package from their site and there does not seem to be an dlls in there and so i downloaded the .net 2 application which contained a single dll called Moxiecode.TinyMCE.dll.  I referenced this dll but still seem to get the same errors. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what this was. There is an AJAX extender called TinyMCETextbox that someone has put together. Once I downloaded and added a reference to it all seemed to work well. Thanks for the input

Answer (score 0):

Presumably they have a build of their app deployed somewhere? Could you not just grab that and track down the assembly from there?